# How to center align custom objects in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to center multiple objects in its view controller. How would I approach this? I am able to center using constraints for one image, but I cannot for multiple as shown below:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your image, labels, and other items. Then `embed` them in a `view`, then add the proper center constraints.

[image]

Comment: Worked, you are a life saver thanks. Sorry if it was too basic of a question ;)

Comment: No problem. I used your question as a chance to figure it out myself and that was my solution.